# How do i find if an object contains an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a huge set of data which is basically an array of objects. I need to loop through all the objects to see if any contain any array themselves.

Thoughts ?

Comment: Define "contain any array".  Contain in properties?  In local variables?

Comment: Try to be more specific both in the problem description and in what you've done thus far that didn't work.

Comment: Well, looping through the objects and checking if any contain an array does sound like it would solve the problem. What problems are you having implementing it?

Comment: I guess it's hard to explain, but I'm pulling in a huge JSON file and then trying to find any nested elements in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to grab only objects that match a condition and then check if any of the values is an array with [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Example:

```
var arr = [
  { x: 1 },
  { x: 2, a: [] },
  { x: 3, a: [] },
  { x: 1 },
];

arr.filter(a => Object.values(a).some(o => o instanceof Array))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var obj = arr[i];

    for (var j in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (obj[j] instanceof Array) {
            console.log(i + '.' + j + ' is array');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you